# Virtual scrolling Not working in Angular with response data- cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: angular, angular-material, virtualscroll

I am not able to bind the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport with data in my Angular html.

This is the data in my **jobLists** array which is assigned with response data in ngOnInit

[image]

In my html class i have sample like this

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
<div *cdkVirtualFor="let currentJob of jobLists">
  <mat-card class="job-list">
    <div class="posted-on">
      <span class="loc">Posted On</span>: {{ currentJob.posteddate }}
    </div>
         
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

I already imported

```
 import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

in my appmodule.ts

I checked project.json CDK is already there.

And when i try to display using normal *ngFor values are displaying without any issues.

Anything else do i need to add to this work?

**UPDATE**

When i try to simply display numbers with 10000 , its coming up correctly. So it looks like the issue with binding value. Any idea whats wrong with my value?

UPDATE 2

I think it has some role with [itemSize]="100" style="height: 900px;overflow-y:auto;"
Now its coming and I modified my .ts

jobToDisplay: any; decalred it like this and assigned

this.jobToDisplay = this.jobLists;

Now its bindingb but when i touch heightproperty it will not bind..

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a fixed height as css rule
when you change the list or the page height you need to control the viewport size

```
this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport? .checkViewportSize ()
```

where

```
@ViewChild (CdkVirtualScrollViewport, {static: false}) cdkVirtualScrollViewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport
```